# Jenkins - Integrating JIRA with Jenkins, for creating ticket automatically when build fails, in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins to run jobs and want to create/update tickets in JIRA, whenever build fails. I have downloaded JIRA plugin, Jira Issue Updater, JiraTestResultReporter plugins and configured URL and credentials, under *Manage Jenkins/Configure System*.

In the job am running, under Post-build Actions, I added '**Create Jira Issue**' with project key, assignee name etc and 'Jira Test Result Reporter' with all required credentials.

I get the following error in the console:

```
ERROR: Publisher 'Jira Test Result Reporter' aborted due to exception: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getTestResultAction()Lhudson/tasks/test/AbstractTestResultAction;
at JiraTestResultReporter.JiraReporter.perform(JiraReporter.java:105)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:726)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:185)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:671)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1769)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:374)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any idea whats going wrong? Is it not able to find the project? I have access to create ticket in the project specified, in jira.

Comment: /java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: /  : check jenkin version, plugin  version.

Comment: Compatability should /may be an issue. Which version of jira is stable with Jenkins? And can tickets be created on fly (in Jira) when build fails in Jenkins? I just want to make sure whatever I am trying is actually possible.

Comment: What I suggested was to check the "plugin" (jar/xpi) version is really compatible with your jenkins version. You can check that from plugin page of jenkin server. Hopefully JIRA apis are more stable.

Comment: Yes I understood. And regarding creating tickets on fly in JIRA, from Jenkins, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally possible to create tickets in JIRA programmatically, for example via their [REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/api-reference/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-create-issue).

Regarding your error, this behavior was introduced when the method signature of `getTestResultAction()` changed to return an `Action` instead of an `AbstractTestResultAction`.
The effect on the JiraTestResultReporter plugin is a known issue and is tracked at [JENKINS-25140](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-25140).
The error was fixed in the source of the plugin a while ago, but is still pending a release.

**Solution:**
As a workaround, Daniel Beck suggests to build and install a snapshot of the current JiraTestResultReporter plugin which seems to solve this particular error (see comments to the Jenkins ticket mentioned above).

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how do I edit the plugin present in Jenkins/Home/plugins/JiraTestResultReporter.        Or, how do I do that code edit, build and snapshot of current plugin?

Comment: To build the plugin from source, grab the code from [github](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JiraTestResultReporter-plugin). Then build it with maven: `mvn install`. This will create the new plugin file at **./target/JiraTestResultReporter.hpi** which you can then upload to your Jenkins in Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugins -> Advanced

Comment: Pulled the code & did the changes shown in the link. But project shows so many errors, which doesn't allow for build or mvn install

Comment: I just successfully tested to build the plugin from source with  
`git clone https://github.com/jenkinsci/JiraTestResultReporter-plugin.git`,  
`cd JiraTestResultReporter-plugin`, then `mvn install`. 
Do you have maven set up on your machine? Maybe the [Jenkins Wiki on Plugin development](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial#Plugintutorial-SettingUpEnvironment) can help you.

Comment: I am using Eclipse with git and maven plugins. I have maven set up too. If you have the edited hpi, can you share it ?

Comment: I have uploaded the [JiraTestResultReporter.hpi](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=19495777607321012511) file that I created from commit [60ce4771..](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JiraTestResultReporter-plugin/commit/60ce4771f3bf104b3def063bcb1251a56cb8aff3). Note that I did not make any changes to the source files myself. It should still be compilable on your machine if maven is installed but I hope this helps.

Comment: I need to decompile/extract this jar and do the code changes and then jar it again using Maven, right?

Comment: There should be no code changes required as I compiled the latest unreleased code from github. The .hpi should be ready to use.